# DateTime Values Get Cropped As Integers

Tags: asp.net, datetime

I'm using a `DateTime` variable and I get minute and hour values to my string variables like:

```
timeValue.Hour.ToString() + ":" +  timeValue.Minute.ToString()
```

But when the values contain `0`'s (zero), they behave like `integer`s and get cropped.

For example: If the time is *19:30*, then my string is like `19:3`. or when it's like *06:00*, the string is `6:0`.

How can I correct this except creating a zero-detector algorythm?

Comment: The second one can be corrected... the first one (i.e. 19:30) can't happen with the code you show - there must some other code relevant to this behaviour... please show the code that sets `timeValue` and the code that processes the result of the above string operation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Hour` and `Minute` **are** `int`egers!

```
timeValue.ToString("HH':'mm")
```

will give you what you want

I have put the `:` between `''` so that it's always a `:` and it isn't the locale-defined time separator (every nation can have a different time separator)

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
timeValue.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Comment: this doesn't explain why 19:30 leads to 19:3 ?

Comment: I am with you but thus I suspect there is some code relevant to this that the OP hasn't posted...

Comment: @Yahia: yes, I saw your comment and I think you're right. Anyway formatting dates manually instaed of using builtin functions is (IMO) wrong. So my solution and Xanatos's one are better than the code OP was using, don't you think? ;)